# file opening dialog & drag and drop in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I want to build a little application; and it has to have some sort of possibility to load files. Right now I am just copying the path into the application, but I do want to build a possibility to

- drop a file from outside into the GUI and
- have a file opening dialog.

Is there a way to accomplish at least one of those requirements? Because I do not want to create a non-native file opening dialog myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an file opening dialog from tkinter.

To get a filename the code will be:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename 
## OR  from tkinter.filedialog import *

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
foo = askopenfilename()
root.destroy()
print(foo)
```

Comment: This is actually what I did now. It just doesn't work under Mac OS, but I am not a huge fan of apple anyways, so I don't care. ^^

Comment: Also, do they file have a custom name, or a name that changes? Such as the user renaming the file.

Comment: It's for including image files provided by the user.